# Create edge from attribute with ArangoDB AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have imported a list of documents (in a collection named "assemblies"). One of the attributes is "parent_id".
Based on this, I want to construct the graph, that is implicitly described by this attribute.

```
"id","name","parent_id"
"30","Top level"
"30.1","30.1 Child 1","30"
"30.2","30.2 Child 2","30"
```

This is the query, that I expected to give me the info for creating the edge collection (named "contains", so it is from parent to child):

```
FOR assy IN assemblies
  LET parent = (
    FOR parent IN assemblies
      FILTER parent.id == assy.parent_id
      RETURN parent
  )
  RETURN {_from: parent._key, _to: assy._key}
```

What am I doing wrong? Could you give me the full query for inserting the edges?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the result of your subquery in `parent` is an array and not an document. But there is actually no need of a subquery. You can also performe a [join](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Examples/Join.html#self-joins), which should offer better performance and is easier to read.
You also have to use the value of `_id` insteadt of `_key` for the fields `_from` and `_to` of your edges.

The following query does exactly what you want.

```
FOR assy IN assemblies
  FOR parent IN assemblies
    FILTER parent.id == assy.parent_id
    INSERT {_from: parent._id, _to: assy._id} IN contains
    RETURN NEW
```

*Node*: the [`RETURN NEW`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Operations/Insert.html#returning-the-inserted-documents) is optional. You can check with it whether the import was successful. With larger amount of data I would drop this.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Turned out the field "id" had two invisible characters in front of it, due to encoding issues. After converting the csv file to basic UTF-8, it worked. I found this out, when I was exporting the collection to json.